# H-bridge 12V DC to 12VAC squarewave output

Tags: mosfet, inverter, h-bridge, msp430, square

I am trying to convert DC to AC, in this case, 12VDC to 12VAC at 50Hz. I am using MSP430G2553 TI microcontroller to create Mosfet gate pulse. Mosfet model is IRFZ44N. The load is a 200 ohm resistor. A 12V 0.2A is set and supplied from a DC power supply to H-bridge. I did a code to put high and low pulses to the gate. I put an oscilloscope probe across the resistor to check the waveform, and it is a square wave but the frequency shows 1.68Hz and period 596ms.Also there are many spikes in the low pulse of the square wave. I also put a multimeter across the resistor to check AC voltage but the reading is unstable and shows 5V, then 7V, and keeps changing, not my desired 12VAC. Also the multimeter shows frequency 200Hz and duty 25%.

Please let me know what changes is needed, and what corrections are needed. Two photos are attached below.

The msp controller coding is given below:

```
#include<msp430g2553.h>

int main(void) {

    WDTCTL = WDTPW | WDTHOLD; // Stop watchdog timer
    P1DIR |= 0x01; // Set P1.0 to output direction
    P1DIR |= 0x40; // Set P1.6 to output direction

    while(1) {
        volatile unsigned long i, j; // Volatile to prevent optimization

        // Turn ON the RED LED
        P1OUT = 0x01;

        // Introduce dead time (adjust based on clock frequency)
        __delay_cycles(160000);  // Adjust this value based on your requirements

        // Turn OFF the RED LED
        P1OUT = 0x00;

        // Introduce dead time (adjust based on clock frequency)
        __delay_cycles(160000);  // Adjust this value based on your requirements

        // Turn ON the GREEN LED
        P1OUT = 0x40;

        // Introduce dead time (adjust based on clock frequency)
        __delay_cycles(160000);  // Adjust this value based on your requirements

        // Turn OFF the GREEN LED
        P1OUT = 0x00;

        // Introduce dead time (adjust based on clock frequency)
        __delay_cycles(160000);  // Adjust this value based on your requirements
    }
}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: The microcontroller output is TTL and does not reach 12v. To drive the high side MOSFET you need to use higher voltage. Use a MOSFET driver or a bridge like L298 that handles the TTL as input and works with a 12V supply for the output drive.

Comment: @Saadat thank you for your response. Really appreciate it. (1)The mosfet gate is responding with microcontroller pulse, so the switching is happening , then why would a  mosfet driver needed? (2)And the voltage 12V is given from dc power supply to mosfet drain so output of H-bridge should have been 12VAC right? Hoping a response from you.

Comment: @user263983 thank you for your response. Really appreciate it. (1) why would there be needed a mosfet driver if the gate is responding according to the MCU pulse? Hoping a response from you.

Comment: @Nabs Driving a high-side Mosfet that is connected to 12V needs the Gate to be able to reach 12V, too. Maybe this link helps: https://www.engineersgarage.com/high-and-low-side-switching-of-mosfet-part-13-17/

Comment: @Saadat, thank you, I will read the article. Thank you for your contribution.